# Errors with shotgun gem and msvcrt-ruby18.dll when running my Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongrel, shotgun

Greetings,

Every time I make a change to a Sinatra app I'm working on and try to refresh the browser (located at http://localhost:4567/) the browser will refresh and, the console window seems to restart the WEB brick server. The problem is that the content in the browser window does not change.

A friend of mine told me it was a shotgun issue and referred me to rtomayko's shotgun gem:

http://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun

On this page I read that the shotgun gem would basically solve my problem, allowing the changes made to my app to show up in the browser window after I refresh it. So I installed the shotgun gem. The installation was successful. To activate the shotgun function you have to type **shotgun** before the file name. In this case my Sinatra app's file name is **shortener.rb**

When I type **shotgun shortener.rb** to run my Sinatra app I get this error:

[alt text http://lh6.ggpht.com/_83PkeFeVNNk/S-ymaYEgDUI/AAAAAAAAArE/rr7uJE3dRj4/shotgun_error.png](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_83PkeFeVNNk/S-ymaYEgDUI/AAAAAAAAArE/rr7uJE3dRj4/shotgun_error.png)

I should also mention that before testing the shotgun method out to see if it worked, I installed the mongrel *(I realize I should have checked to see if shotgun worked before doing this as installing mongrel has complicated this problem)*. So on top of getting the error message above I also get this pop up window from Ruby.exe

[alt text http://lh6.ggpht.com/_83PkeFeVNNk/S-ymaaWIZKI/AAAAAAAAArA/8qYCGUN8Wo4/msvcrt-ruby18.dll_error.png](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_83PkeFeVNNk/S-ymaaWIZKI/AAAAAAAAArA/8qYCGUN8Wo4/msvcrt-ruby18.dll_error.png)

I have no idea what **msvcrt-ruby18.dll** is but I know that installing either **shotgun** and/or **mongrel** created this problem.

Where to go from here?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: I discovered that the shotgun gem is not working because it requires fork(2) which is not available on Windows. That solves that issue.

Comment: I would just like to say that in consulting with some developer friends, I have come to the conclusion that I will no longer attempt to develop in Ruby and Sinatra on Windows. I have installed Virtual Box and Ubuntu 10.4 on my Windows Vista 64 machine so I may create a virtual machine (VM) that will run Ubuntu Linux. 

Check out this blog post about how Joon You develops on his Windows machine using Virtual Box and Ubuntu: http://blog.rubyhead.com/2010/05/14/if-youre-using-windows/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *msvcrt-ruby18.dll* error is caused by Mongrel. The current release version 1.1.5 is incompatible with Ruby 1.9 and throws this error when it is run. It's easy to solve - just make sure gems is up-to-date:

```
gem update --system
```

Then install the new pre-release version of Mongrel:

```
gem install mongrel --pre
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks Charles. Your answer was a big help for this new Sinatra user on Windows.